# Is it possible to have Server Blazor Razor component rendered as static within the parent razor component which is rendered as ServerPrerended?

Tags: razor, blazor

Example:
ParentControl.razor

```
<ParentControl>
    <ChildControl /> <!-- this should be rendered as static -->
    <SomeOtherChildControl />
</ParentControl>
```

in _Host.cshtml

```
<component type="typeof(ParentControl)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

In ParentControl.razor I can't use tag helper  so I can't set render-mode="static".
I don't have control over how will be ParentControl rendered so I would like to know **if is possible to have the child component rendered as static even though ParentControl is "ServerPrerendered"**?

I spent a lot of time going through the ASP.NET Core Blazor documentation, but I didn't find a way how to do it.

Comment: Great question and to add to the confusion. I would want to render a component as static but with a serverprerendered component inside.